# Changing graphics coordinates to the image coordinate frame

Tags: graphics, image-processing

The graphics libraries I'm used to using with images, all use image coordinate frames.  That is, the origin is in the upper left hand corner.

I'm relatively new to using Mathematica for image processing and the Graphics command.

Having the coordinate frame for graphics overlays in the lower left hand corner is causing me endless headaches, as all annotations/overlays/JSON files etc. from the other products/projects I use, all have upper left hand corner as the origin.

Here is an example generated with this code:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{10, 20}, {30, 60}]}]]
```

[image]

Is there some function foo I can wrap around my Graphics object such that, if I did this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
Show[img, 
 foo[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{10, 20}, {30, 60}]}]]]
```

I'm looking for something operating at the high "graphics" level, not something I have to do for each individual graphics primitive....

[image]

Comment: does `height = Last@ImageDimensions[img];
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{10, 1 + height - 20}, {30, 1 + height - 60}]}]]` give what you need?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying.  That's the correct transformation.

Comment: But, that doesn't get me what I need.  How does one map that across all the graphics objects such that they render properly?  I can do it by hand for individual cases.  I was hoping for a way to do it more automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that might work, though I'm not sure if it would break in some cases:

```
flip[height_?NumericQ][g : Graphics[p_, options___]] := 
 Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
   p, {{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {0, height}}], options]
```

Then `flip[imageheight][Graphics[...]]` gets you what you want! But we can do better by packaging this into a custom version of `Show`:

```
ImageShow[img_Image, graphics___Graphics] :=
 Show[img, Sequence @@ (flip[ImageDimensions[img][[2]]] /@ {graphics})]
```

Then simply using it in place of `Show` gets you what you want, e.g. `ImageShow[img, Graphics[...]]`. (By the way, I checked—I was worried about being off-by-one, but I think this puts the origin at the right place!)

EDIT: It was mentioned that `Text` works...well, undesirably, appearing upside down. So, I created different versions of the above functions that correct text by default, but allow an option to be passed to turn this off.

```
ClearAll[flip, ImageShow]

correctText[Text[text_, options___Rule]] := 
 GeometricTransformation[Text[text, options], {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]

correctText[Text[text_, {x_, y_}, args___]] := 
 GeometricTransformation[Text[text, {x, -y}, args], {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]

correctText[Text[text_, Scaled[{x_, y_}], args___]] := 
 GeometricTransformation[Text[text, Scaled[{x, -y}], args], {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]

correctText[Text[text_, Scaled[{dx_, dy_}, {x_, y_}], args___]] := 
 GeometricTransformation[
  Text[text, Scaled[{dx, -dy}, {x, -y}], args], {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]

SetAttributes[correctText, Listable]

correctText[x_] := x

flip[height_?NumericQ, OptionsPattern[{CorrectText -> True}]][g : Graphics[p_, options___]] := 
 Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
   If[OptionValue[CorrectText], correctText[p], 
    p], {{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {0, height}}], options]

ImageShow[img_Image, graphics___Graphics, opts : OptionsPattern[{CorrectText -> True}]] := 
 Show[img, 
  Sequence @@ (flip[ImageDimensions[img][[2]], opts] /@ {graphics})]

(* Test: *)

img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}];
ImageShow[img, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Text["ABCDEF", {50, 20}], Rectangle[{10, 20}, {30, 60}]}]]

ImageShow[img, 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Text["ABCDEF", {50, 20}], Rectangle[{10, 20}, {30, 60}]}], CorrectText -> False]
```

Comment: Interestingly, and not surprisingly, the Text graphics directive renders text upside down with this solution....

Comment: @John Good point! I updated the answer to correct for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to @thorimur's response, is to make use of [HighlightImage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightImage.html).

This does essentially what was requested, i.e. provide a way to place arbitrary graphics objects over an image similar to Show, while making use of image coordinates, instead of graphics coordinates.

Comment: HightlightImage has (0,0) in the lower left corner.